# Surface where Hopf Rinow's theorem is not worth

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

In Hopf Rinow's Theorem we see that if $S$ is a complete surface then we have: for all $p,q \in S$ there is $\gamma$ a minimizing geodesic that connects them. However, as long as the reciprocal of this result does not occur, this may be true even if $S$ is not complete. So I would like to ask if anyone knows a surface example (obviously not complete) where there are two $p,q$ points, such that there is no minimizing geodesic that connects them. I thought of the cone without the vertex, but couldn't find such points. Thank you for your help

Comment: If you want to find your example on the cone, make a cone out of a sector of a circle, but make sure your central angle is $>\pi$. Two points close to but on opposite sides of the center of the circle will work when you fold the sector up into a cone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2 / \{0\}$ and let $x,y$ be two points on one of the axis but on different semiplanes, let us say $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. Obviously no minimizing geodesic can join $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Is possible to introduce a metric on punctured plane such that this manifold being to complete?